# Conversion of page Geometry to Typearea with scrbook Koma Script

Tags: geometry, scrbook, typearea

I've read that I shouldn't use the `geometry` package with KOMA-Script.  So, I would like to convert my page layout to something similar using Koma-Scripts built in `typearea` features.

```
\documentclass[american,headings=openany]{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} %\input{headersfooters}
\usepackage{microtype}  
\usepackage{setspace} \onehalfspacing
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%
% % % these font packages require a full install %
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt} % monospace font %
\usepackage{libris}             % san serif font %
\usepackage{tgschola}           % roman font     %
%
%
\usepackage[paperwidth=5.06in,paperheight=7.81in]{geometry}
   \geometry{verbose,tmargin=0.75in,bmargin=0.75in,%
     lmargin=0.7in,rmargin=0.4in,headheight=0.25in,%
     headsep=0.2in,footskip=0.4in}%
%
\begin{document}

% \input{mybook} % I will input many chapters %

Hello World, this will be my book.

\end{document}
```

Can anyone provide me the `typearea` code that would replace `geometry` with similar results?  It does not have to be exact.  I want to learn which `typearea` options I will need, and what adjustments I need to tinker with.  I've read through the `scrguien.pdf` but it's not sinking in very well (I'm still confused).  But so far I've read about the `BCOR=` and `DIV=` options, the possible values for `DIV`, especially the numeric values, the `last` value, the `areaset` value.  And the `\typearea` command.  But I have no idea what to do with them.

Comment: Please provide something people can compile which doesn't rely on files only you have.

Comment: Done.  I it should compile now.  But the book will be tiny.

Answer (score 6):

Well, at last you can read the definition of the page layout with `typearea` in the documentation of KOMA-Script, page 24, chapter `Construction of the Page Layout with typearea` (you can open it with `texdoc komascript`.

You can also use package [`layout`](http://ctan.org/pkg/layout) or package [`layouts`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/layouts) to check the resulting values for different parameters for `typearea` (documentation: `texdoc layout` or `texdoc layouts`).

The main difference between `geometry` and `typearea` is, that `typearea` **calculates** an optimal typing area depending on the used fontsize but `geometry` "only" uses the given values for margins etc to create a typing area. With `geometry` there is no algorithm to calculate an typing area depending on the fontsize.

So if you want a good looking typography for the page (and you do not know what is a good typography) use `typearea` to calculate a good looking page.  If you have to follow rules given by your university for margins etc. then it is easier to use `geometry` to fullfill the rules.

Comment: Hi, I don't really know what a "good looking" typography is.  Typearea sounds like a good option for me.  I do have a couple of rules: there needs to be at minimum 0.25" margin.  (The pages will be printed on a larger stock and trimmed, and the result is that there's a plus/minus 0.25" cutting error, so everything could get shifted one way or the other by up to 0.25"  Anything closer to edge could get cropped out.)  They advise 0.5" margins or greater so nothing will be on the edge.  Also I have several pagesize inch options to pick from 5x8.25 8.5x5.5 or 5.06x7.81. (How do I use areaset?)

Comment: Perhaps you would find this useful *A Few Notes on Book Design* by myself. Available via `texdoc memdesign`

Comment: @PeterWilson, it's working when I type it [full texlive distribution].